# add class every 5 items(div) when i click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to add class every 5 items(div) when i click on button
Does anybody know how to add class every 5 elements using jQuery's each?

```
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href=#]').click(function() {

           $('.element-item').each(function(i+5) {
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/8yuqb5u3/

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $('.element-item:not(.newClass)').each(function(ix) {
    $(this).addClass('newClass')
    return (ix < 4)
  })
})
```

Returning a false value will exit the each function.

Pass the index to the each function and return ix < 4 since index is 0 based.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.slice` to get a range of elements. You can see the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/slice/

`$('.element-item').slice(0,5).addClass('class_name');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on the question but provided two possible answers to what I think you're asking for:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href="#"]').on('click', function() {
        // Every 5th element
        $('.element-item:nth-child(5n)').addClass('sample');

        // First 5 elements
        $('.element-item:lt(5)').addClass('sample');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first parameter (indexInArray) of the jQuery [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to get the index of the array.

Then you can use the [Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) to add the class for every fifth item.

Maybe this example can get you started:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href=#]').click(function() {
    $('.element-item').each(function( index, value ) {
      var itemNumber = index + 1;
      if (itemNumber % 5 === 0) {
        $(value).addClass('newClass');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.newClass {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.element-item {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">link</a>

<div class="element-item">element 1</div>
<div class="element-item">element 2</div>
<div class="element-item">element 3</div>
<div class="element-item">element 4</div>
<div class="element-item">element 5</div>
<div class="element-item">element 6</div>
<div class="element-item">element 7</div>
<div class="element-item">element 8</div>
<div class="element-item">element 9</div>
<div class="element-item">element 10</div>
<div class="element-item">element 11</div>
```